# How to get users calendar event in microsoft graph api

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I have registered an app in the azure portal for an organization. With the graph api I am able to access all users present in the tenant using graph api `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`.

This is the process that I am using to get an individual user's calendar:

1. graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users.
2. copy `id/userPrincipalName` of a user.
3. graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/id/calendars/events.

In this process I am getting 403 forbidden.

Please let me know if my approach is correct or not.

Answer (score 5):

403 means that your Azure AD app doesn't have enough permissions to access the events.

If you are using [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0), you need add `Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite` Application permissions into your app.

If you are using [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0), you need to add `Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite` Delegated permissions into your app.

See the required permissions from [List events Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

For how to add API permissions, you could refer to [Manage API permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-app-registration#api-permissions).

---

**Update**

Take Application permission: **Calendars.Read** as an example.

After you add the permission in Azure AD app, don't forget to click on the "Grant admin consent for ***" button at the bottom.
[image]

And then use [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) to get the access token.
[image]

After getting the access token, call the calendar events endpoint.
[image]

The format of the value of Authorization is "Bearer {access_token from the last step}".

---

**Update 2:**
[image]

Comment: All of these permission are given.  I am trying these api call in postman.  Can you please let me know what should be the url and body param I need to add.

Comment: Admin consent is given for all permission as mentioned above. Below are the details which i am referring to get access token in postman:- Grant Type- Authorization code, callack url:- https://app.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback ,Auth Url- https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.microsoft.com, Access Token URL- https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0,Client ID- {client id} , client secret- {secret},Scope- User.Read.All openid offline_access profile User.Read Calendar.Read, please let me know what is wrong in that.

Comment: The params seem to be OK. Please add a screenshot of the API permissions in your Azure AD app. Thus I can see if there is anything wrong. In this case, you need to add Calendars.Read or Calendars.ReadWrite Delegated permission rather than Application permission.

Comment: please find permission screenshot.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aLDg.png

Comment: Please don't add anything as an answer if it is not an answer. You can delete it. And I have tested in Postman with your params. Everything works fine. Please make sure that you are using the correct client ID. And you can decode your access_token from https://jwt.io/ to see if it has the correct permissions.

Comment: We are getting access token but with that token not able to hit graph api. Invalid access token error is coming. For server to server interaction client credential grant type i am using. Okhttp client i am using with header grant type client credential and body client id,client secret,scope. Do we need to add resourcre and redirect uri as well for a valid access token?

Comment: I see. So I guess you are calling v2.0 endpoint. In this case, you should set "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" as the value for Scope. See my update in answer.

Comment: Thanks Allen... I calling V1.0 end point only. I got the solution.

Comment: If you are calling v1.0 endpoint, you just need to modify "scope" to "resource". The value of it should be "https://graph.microsoft.com". That's enough. "scope" is used in v2.0. Anyway, glad to know your issue is resolved.

Comment: can you please let me know how to get all calendar event including recurring events.I am currently using  "/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events" but recurring events are not coming.

Comment: I don' t have "Grant admin consent for ***" button.
How do I grant admin consent ?